# Filter date time google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I filter the data to be filtered with the filters cells?

Please be aware that data in column AA has +10k rows.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=FILTER(AA:AA, MATCH(AA:AA, Y2:Y3,0))
```

That should filter the dates matching the 2 cells that you want.

Answer (score 2):

The filter command does a good job.

```
=FILTER(AA5:AA,AA5:AA >= Y1, AA5:AA <= Y2)
```

[Here are the docs for it](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en), honestly it is my favorite formula.